# If I'm extremely hungry, I'm 'famished'; if I'm extremely thirsty, I'm .....?

Tags: word-request, word-usage

I know the word that describes extreme hunger.

> I'm hungry. I can wait for food for some time. 
>   I'm famished, waiting is not possible.

[Famished](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/famished) is very hungry. Since there's a word to describe 'extreme hunger', I'm pretty sure there must be a word for 'extreme thirst'.

> I'm thirsty. But I can wait for water to come. 
>   I'm **________**, waiting is not possible.

What's the word to fill in the blank?

Comment: I usually think of *famished* as "having no food for quite some time", so in this sense, *dehydrated* would work perfectly fine for me. However, you probably are looking for *parched*.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I thought *parched* is used for *drying out* and thus is closed to *dehydration*. Being a healthcare provider, I know the difference between being *extremely thirsty* and the state of *dehydration.* But yes, looking at OALD, *parched* is possibly the word. Thanks :)

Comment: @LucianSava nice but looking for an adjective

Comment: I'd vote for parched if it were presented as an answer.

Comment: @Chris- So would I.

Comment: @DamkerngT. ***Parched*** is the word. I went through several references. Kindly post is as an answer.

Comment: Some of the younger generation will routinely just say, "I'm ***way thirsty***"

Comment: @Jim thanks for making me somewhat younger! :) I'll practice that when I'm with adolescents. haha.

Comment: @MaulikV Thanks for accepting my comment. :) The reason I didn't post it as answer was that I was, and still is, reluctant to say *parched* is to *famished* as *thirsty* is to *hungry*. (To me, *parched* is more to *starving*; and *dehydrated* is to *famished*.) That might sound odd, but it probably really is what I feel, though I feel fine to hear people say (as in Jim's comment) "I'm famished, what's for dinner?" or "I'm parched, I'm gonna go get a soda.". Also, my natural choice would be "I'm really thirsty" and possibly "way thirsty". I won't mind if someone else post *parched* as answer.

Comment: @DamkerngT.: I'm curious - what difference in meaning do you see between *starving* and *famished*?

Comment: @Martha Not much. It's difficult to explain. I think it's like when we express the same thing but from different points of view. It's like sometimes that I feel *have to* and *must* are interchangeable and sometimes they aren't. Probably, *starving* is more emotional and *famished* is more factual. That's just my feeling (and of course, opinion), anyway.

Comment: @DamkerngT.: huh, I have the opposite impression - *famished*, being the more metaphorical word (or exaggerated one - applying a famine to a single person), is the more emotional one, and *starving* is the word that can be used factually, though it often isn't.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The drink parallel of *famished* is *parched*.

> **[parch](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/parched)**
>   <sub>Dictionary.com main section</sub>
>   5. *verb (used without object)* to suffer from heat, thirst, or need of water.
>   <sub>Dictionary.com "World English Dictionary" section</sub>
>   2. (*tr; usually passive*) to make very thirsty: *I was parched after the run*

*Dehydrated* is a more clinical term, and would be parallel to *malnourished*, I think.

Both *famished* and *parched* can be used in both formal and informal contexts, although they're frequently used with a bit of hyperbole implied, which skews them toward the informal.

> I'm so parched I think I could drink a river.

There are also a *lot* of idioms out there to signify extreme thirst, such as the "spitting cotton" one mentioned by CopperKettle, but if you're looking for the most straightforward parallel to *famished*, then you really can't do better than *parched*.

Answer (score 2):

I've just recalled one Southern expression I learned from [Shelby Foote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shelby_Foote)'s *[Civil War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Civil_War:_A_Narrative)*, so I'll add it as my 2¢:

> I'm thirsty. But I can wait for water to come. 
>  I'm (so dry I'm) **spitting cotton**, waiting is not possible.

I have no idea how widely it's used now.

Comment: This is a nice one! Also related are 'spitting feathers' and 'spitting chips', though ['spitting feathers' seems to also have another meaning](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/spitting-feathers.html).